# youtube feed api orderby parameter not showing up all results

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, sql-order-by, feed

I am implementing youtube api for searching videos. I have noticed that search results differ by changing orderby parameter's value. There is one video which shows up with "published" but not with "viewCount". I know, list order will change by changing parameters.

While using viewCount for orderby parameter, videos with lesser view count are visible but some specific video is not listed having large viewCount. And same video can be found by using   "published" for orderby.

Kindly explain, how exactly youtube api works.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On an ongoing basis, statistics for a video are typically updated every 30 minutes to two hours. However, updates may occur less frequently under heavy server loads or for videos that are viewed very infrequently. In search feeds, updates to ratings and view counts could take as long as a couple of weeks for infrequently viewed videos.

The YouTube Data API retrieves search results from a specially optimized search index. The index is designed to include new videos as quickly as possible while ensuring high performance even under heavy API server loads. For more info see here: [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference)